# Unable to get aview to produce an image

Tags: ascii, aview

I have installed [`aview`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/aview.1.html) the ASCII art image viewer with:

```
sudo apt-get install aview
```

But now when I run it with:

```
aview /path/to/image.extension
```

I get this:

```
Invalid magic-not p?m family format
```

I have tried getting this to work with the following image formats so far, and still the same output: `png`, `jpg`, and `bmp`.

Why is this happening? And how do I fix this, or use `aview` correctly if I am using it wrong?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

```
aview:
  Installed: 1.3.0rc1-9
  Candidate: 1.3.0rc1-9
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.0rc1-9 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** apparently if you invoke the program as `asciiview` instead of `aview`, it will automagically do the file conversion for you

```
asciiview somefile.png
```

---

**Original answer:**

The `p?m` refers to the [libpnm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnm.html) family of "lowest common denominator" image files, including `pbm` and `pgm`. If you convert your image to one of those formats, for example using the `convert` tool from the `imagemagick` package

```
convert somefile.png somefile.pgm
```

(or using `gimp` if you prefer) it should work, e.g.

```
aview somefile.pgm
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically use pnm with aview.
You can convert to pnm with Gimp also.